# PHP SELECT * FROM users WHERE usersname=R*

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can you make from the * a wildcard so when i search for a user i type in like

Firstname: R*
Lastname: *

and it will look for users where the firstname starts with R or

Firstname: *
Lastname: R*

and it will look for user where the lastname starts with R.

Comment: The wildcard for `like` in MySQL is `'%'`.

Comment: I'm surprised you haven't heard of the search machine [Google](http://www.google.com). It's an amazing tool when programming - the term "*MySQL wildcard*" would've given you about 811,000 results, and it would've even faster than asking SO for help!

Comment: I`m 9 years old what did you expect...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `*` rather you need to do like `R%` and that will get you all lastname starts with `R` letter

```
select * from table1
where Lastname like 'R%'
```

Comment: @user3625270, This is the correct way of achieving what you are looking for. don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE 'R%';
```